# how to open a new page in nodejs and display user data

Tags: node.js, redirect

Hi I am new to nodejs and am trying to redirect to a new page to display a single record when I click on the edit button. I am not sure how the routes work.
if I browse to:
http://localhost:1337/ I see a table with all the users in it. I have added a column that says edit, but when I click edit I am trying to run a function that findsone record which then opens the pug page: localhost:1337/userInfo.

if I just browse to: localhost:1337/userInfo then I see the same table as in http://localhost:1337/ because it is linked to the global.js file which has all the code in it. So I am not sure how this routing works and how to go to the userInfo page on edit and only view the single record from the function in global.js. Some code below:

**users.js**

```
router.get('/findOneUser/:id', function (req, res) {

var db = req.db;
var id = req.params.id;
var reg = new RegExp(id)
var collection = db.get('userlist');
ccollection.find({ '_id': { $regex: reg }}, function (e, docs) {
    res.json(docs);
});
```

});

global.js

```
function populateTable(newuser) {

// Empty content string
var tableContent = '';
Json = '/users/userlist';

//Compile getJSON Statement
if (newuser !== '' ) {


    Json = '/users/findUser/' + newuser;

}


// jQuery AJAX call for JSON
$.getJSON(Json, function (data){
    // Stick our user data array into a userlist variable in the global object
    userListData = data;
    // For each item in our JSON, add a table row and cells to the content string
    $.each(data, function () {
        //Get the date from MongoDB and convert to local format
        var dt = new Date(this.DOB).toLocaleDateString();

        tableContent += '<tr>';
        tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkshowuser" rel="' + this.username + '">' + this.username + '</a></td>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + this.email + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + dt + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkdeleteuser" rel="' + this._id + '">delete</a></td>';
        tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkupdateuser" rel="' + this._id + '">edit</a></td>';
        tableContent += '</tr>';
    });

    // Inject the whole content string into our existing HTML table
    $('#userList table tbody').html(tableContent);
});
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have a typo inside your `users.js`
It meant to be

```
var collection = db.get('userlist');
collection.find({ '_id': { $regex: reg }}, function (e, docs) {
    res.json(docs);
});
```

And if you want to find only one result, you can use

```
// Of course, I assume you're using Mongoose
var collection = db.get('userlist');
collection.findOne({ '_id': { $regex: reg }}, function (e, docs) {
    res.json(docs);
});
```

And about your front end, you don't even give the `edit` button a link

```
$.getJSON(Json, function (data){
    // Stick our user data array into a userlist variable in the global object
    userListData = data;
    // For each item in our JSON, add a table row and cells to the content string
    $.each(data, function () {
        //Get the date from MongoDB and convert to local format
        var dt = new Date(this.DOB).toLocaleDateString();

        tableContent += '<tr>';
        tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkshowuser" rel="' + this.username + '">' + this.username + '</a></td>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + this.email + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + dt + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkdeleteuser" rel="' + this._id + '">delete</a></td>';
        tableContent += '<td><a href=/findOneUser/'+ this._id +' class="linkupdateuser" rel="' + this._id + '">edit</a></td>';
        tableContent += '</tr>';
    });

    // Inject the whole content string into our existing HTML table
    $('#userList table tbody').html(tableContent);
});
```